# How to deploy ASP.NET Core Project in Windows?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have compiled my existing ASP.NET MVC 5 project to ASP.NET Core. Compilation completed without any issue. How should I deploy this project in windows ???

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link  they provide step by step on how to deploy .Net Core project
https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned anything about web server. I am assuming you are trying to deploy in IIS.

Anyways, here is a proper step by step explanation with sufficient visualization.
https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/publishing/iis.html

Hope this helps ...